# Reactive Forms with Multiple Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am very new to Angular2/4 and trying few things.

I am trying to use **reactive forms** in Angular4 and I am trying to get 3 dropdowns to show data like below:-

I want to design a filter bar, which will allow a user to filter items based on the options available.

There are 3 elements here,

1. Customers (DropDown1)
2. Sites (DropDown2)
3. Assets (DropDown3)

Customers have MANY SITES, Sites have MANY ASSETS.

Scenarios

Scenario 1 - When the user clicks on the customer 1, he should see all the sites and assets available in the drop down

Scenario 2 - When they user clicks on the sites 1 under customer 1, he should see ONLY the assets in that site

Scenario 3 - Is the same as 2, the user clicks on site 2 under customer 2, he should see the assets ONLY under this site

Scenario 4 - This is the same as 1, 2, 3, just a different customer is clicked.

JSON Data is like below:-

```js
import { User } from './models/user';

export const DATA: User[] =
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Customer 1",
        "sites": [
                    {"id": 2, "name": "Site 1", "assets": [{"id": 3, "name": "Asset 1"}] },
                    {"id": 4, "name": "Site 2", "assets": [{"id": 5, "name": "Asset 2"}] },
                    {"id": 6, "name": "Site 3", "assets": [{"id": 7, "name": "Asset 3"}] }
                 ]
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Customer 2",
        "sites": [
                    {"id": 9, "name": "Site 4", "assets": [{"id": 10, "name": "Asset 4"}] },
                    {"id": 11, "name": "Site 5", "assets": [{"id": 12, "name": "Asset 5"}] },
                    {"id": 13, "name": "Site 6", "assets": [{"id": 14, "name": "Asset 6"}] }
                 ]
    },

    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Customer 3",
        "sites": [
                    {"id": 16, "name": "Site 7", "assets": [{"id": 17, "name": "Asset 7"}] },
                    {"id": 18, "name": "Site 8", "assets": [{"id": 19, "name": "Asset 8"}] },
                    {"id": 20, "name": "Site 9", "assets": [{"id": 21, "name": "Asset 9"}] }
                 ]
    }
]
```

Service is like below:-

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from './models/user';
import { DATA } from './mock-data';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  getData(): Promise<User[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(DATA);
  }
}
```

HTML is like below:-

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Customer Details</h1><br>

    <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>

      <div class="col-md-4" id="firstname">
          <select id="customernames" formControlName="customernames">
            <option *ngFor="let d of data">
                  {{d.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4" id="firstname">
          <select id="sites" formControlName="sites">
            <option *ngFor="let d of data">
                  {{d.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4" id="firstname">
          <select id="assets" formControlName="assets">
            <option *ngFor="let d of data">
                  {{d.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
      </div>

    </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Component is like below:-

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { User } from './models/user';
import { UserService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  data: User[];
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {

  }

  getData(): void {
     this.userService.getData().then(response => this.data = response);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();

    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        customernames: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        sites: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        assets: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
  }

}
```

So I created reactive form following as below link:-

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Also I looked into Dynamic Forms below but they confused me:-

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Questions:-

1. How can I put data into those dropdowns (I was only able to do that for customer names)
2. Should I use Dynamic Form approach and how?
3. How will then I achieve selecting a scenario like:-

   Customer1 (selected in 1st Dropdown) ---> Sites (2nd dropdown has sites related to Cutomer1) ---> Assets (Assets as per Sites)

> Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe you need to use dynamic forms for this approach.

My approach would be just to all the logic in your html file.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Customer Details</h1><br>

    <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>

      <div class="col-md-4" >
        <select  formControlName="customernames">
          <option *ngFor="let user of userData" [ngValue]="user">
            {{user.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select  formControlName="sites"  >
          <option *ngFor="let site of myForm.get('customernames').value.sites" [ngValue]="site">
            {{site.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4" >
        <select formControlName="assets" >
          <option *ngFor="let asset of myForm.get('sites').value.assets" [ngValue]="asset">
            {{asset.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is not a robust solution but hopefully gives you an idea.